# What is this thing: "\x30\xff\xff\x31\xff\xff\xff\xff" called?

Tags: c, shellcode

everyone! I'm studying C for a while now. and right now, while I'm visiting XDA Developers for my phone, I came across this code:

```
char next_ptr[8] = "\x30\xff\xff\x31\xff\xff\xff\xff";
```

is this like an array of hexadecimal codes or what? However, I noticed that when I count how many of these values are inbetween the brackets have the same value with `char next_ptr[8]`. and beacause I remembered the word "shellcode", In searching the word shellcode in google with images, I noticed that here are some snippets of code in the images that has these forms.

I've tried to convert them to text like so:

converting it in the original form:
[image: Here]

converting it with the original hexadecimal form:
[image: Here]

I don't know what's the name of this syntax so I didn't search for it please shed some light for me. Thank you!

Comment: The `\x30` is  an "escape sequence" with the byte value `0x30`. So there are 8 butes defined, just right for that array.

Comment: convert text to hexa is the wrong tool... In Ascii `0x30` is `'0'` and `0x31` is `'1'`. But `0xFF` is out of range of ascii (so need to know encoding chosen).

Comment: ok i'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called *hexadecimal escape sequences*. It's basically just an optional way of writing this:

```
char next_ptr[8] = {0x30, 0xff, 0xff, 0x31, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff};
```

(The null terminator of the string literal gets discarded.)

It has nothing to do with [shellcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode).

Also notably, it is naive to store `0xFF` inside a `char`, because it isn't guaranteed to be large enough to store one, since `char` has implementation-defined signedness and might only be able to store positive values up to `0x7F`. The correct data type for storing raw data is `uint8_t`.

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with shellcode but I just need to add that tag because I think shell codes contains codes with this formatting. correct me if i'm wrong...

Comment: The standard is not exactly clear how a hexadecimal or octal escape sequence value that represents an `unsigned char` value but is outside the range of `char` is supposed to be converted to an `int` value or initialize a `char`. C18 (or C11) 6.4.4.4/13 (EXAMPLE 2) only covers 2's complement representations. (This is probably a moot point because the next version of the C standard looks like it is getting rid of non 2's complement representations!)